# Creating an android app that lets you add contacts and products and then view them in a custom listview (Android Studio)(java)

Tags: java, android-studio

I want to create an app that starts up having two buttons on the middle of the screen...by clicking on button:

**Button One:** takes you to a new Activity and It's shows custom contact list

*Take a look what I mean on picture below*
Picture2: https://i.gyazo.com/9f7e80b458dcad001dd4b375ecfc595e.png
also if you hold on a contact, It will open an actvitiy where you can edit it

**Button Two:** Takes you to a new Activity but something like the picture below
Picture3: https://i.gyazo.com/c7714ac0bc998e31cf8c1b4abaf9a50d.png

and an option to delete products or contacts

Can someone help me with the app...Link me the right tutorials or share the source code with me. Anything useful.
I'm doing this in Android Studio...and I'm a beginner Android Studio user.
I never programmed in java before.
I programmed in C++ at school and a little bit of C#.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

what your looking is for a listview and a simple add or delete elements from a an array, list or file depending on how volatile and size you want or need it to be. heres a simple tutorial for starters https://www.raywenderlich.com/124438/android-listview-tutorial work your way up from there. the search function (since I am guessing you just started coding ) can just be a compare string statement that goes through your selected method of storage.